# Django ORM - ForeignKey with 3 models involved

Tags: django, django-orm

I have the following models:

```
class A(models.Model):
    ...

class B(models.Model):
    a = models.ForeignKey(A)
    c = models.ForeignKey(C, null=True, blank=True)

class C(models.Model):
    ...
```

I would like to get all A's that have any B, that have any C = null.
I have tried doing

```
A.objects.filter(b__c__isnull=True)
```

but that isn't fetching the correct results apparently.

Am I missing something?

Comment: a ForeignKey needs to refer to a model field, not a model class (as you have it). If this is just pseudo-code you should post your models and describe why your query isn't fetching the correct results.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try with `a.b_set.filter(c__isnull=True)` , first we ask for the model A, then we ask for the objects B inside A but filtered with c == Null

Answer (score 0):

If your problem is that the A's that don't have any B's are coming, can you try

```
A.objects.filter(b__isnull=False, b__c__isnull=True).distinct()
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to do here a reverse lookup first

```
b_with_c_null = b.objects.filter(c__is_null=True).all()
a_with_any_b_with_c_null = b_with_c_null.a_set.all()
```